# Rigid body objects converted to mesh from a particle system don't get simulated

Tags: particles, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have created 100 cube meshes from a Particle emitter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
Then I have hidden the emitter.

However, when I try to play the animation, the new objects don't follow the Physics.
By the way, all the generated objects have rigid body properties.
So what am I missing here?

Attached the original blender file: [link from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w-nWBx_axubqo0RbDMpLwtFGfr2KKzHk)

[image]

Comment: I've uploaded the blend file to Blend Exchange (a more permanent place to store them) : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4690" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4690/)
(can't edit it into the question since there's a pending edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have originally assigned Rigid Body properties to your "reference" cube (the one that got duplicated by the particle system).

Even though this effectively assigns the Rigid Body properties to the child objects, **it doesn't automatically add them to the `RigidBodyWorld` group**, that is the group that the physics engine takes into consideration when baking dynamics (unless otherwise specified in the rigid body settings).

You can see that they are not part of a group by observing that their wireframe is not colored green.

There is a quick fix to this: **select all your boxes and hit "*Add active*"** in the "*Physics*" panel of the toolbox to the left of the 3D window.

[image]